How to set sample text in TFontDialog?
How to replace the "AaBb..." sample text? Why is the sample text not shown by default when executing TFontDialog? (it seems to show the text only if I click on a font size, even if I set the dialog's font size).
Or, can you suggest a better working alternative for TFontDialog with source code? Maybe one that properly handles font names like "Semibold", "Light", etc. as for example the "Segoe UI" font
has.

Sample text was not showing because of fdNoSizeSel set in Options (size selection still shown anyway so it's a pretty useless flag)

If you enable Skia, it looks like you don't get a font dialog at all, but you do gain access to various weights of text, from Black to UltraLight, and 'stretch' from Condensed to UltraExpanded.

I may end up doing my own fontdialog form, it's pretty easy to collect font names to a ListBox with just this:   Items := Screen.Fonts
